# How to return an empty object of Type Custom Bean in java?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, postman

I have an api which fetches the login Details of an user. It is of a bean type which has the necessary fields. In case the user has not logged in, the object is returned as null. How do I prevent the object to not return null and instead just return an empty object?

Current API Response if the user exists :-

```
"loginDetails": {
            "loginTime": "2019-09-23 06:54:45.0",
            "created": "2019-11-18 05:23:10.0",
            "updated": "2019-11-25 04:23:01.0"
        }
```

Response if the user does not exist :-

```
"loginDetails": null
```

I want to change the above response to an empty object. I tried using a list. But that changed the structure of my API. I don't want to change the structure of an API. I just don't want to return null and instead just return an empty object. How do I change the response? I'm using spring-boot for the backend and jooq to write my sql queries.

Comment: `if (loginDetails == null) new LoginDetails();`

Answer (score 0):

just write below code:

```
if(loginDetails==null){
 return new LoginDetails();//create empty object
}
```

so the response will return as below if user not found:

```
"loginDetails": {
        "loginTime": null,
        "created": null,
        "updated": null
    }
```